# Using views to link two databases

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, entity-framework

A quick rundown. I'm creating a Entity Framework and VB project. The new project will not write any data to the secondary database, it will have its own database where all the new information is stored. However the new project will gather information from the secondary database.

So I have created Views within the projects database that retrieve information from the secondary database. Using the following SQL Statements.

```
SELECT SecondaryDB.Schema.Table.Column From SecondaryDB.Schema.Table
```

Essentially, I'm hoping to accomplish a number of objectives.

- I don't want any changes to the secondary database to occur.
- I would like to have this all under one Model in Entity Framework.
- Controlling access to the information handled by the project and its database.

My question is, is this a reasonable solution, given my requirements? I'm fairly new to EF (by the way I'm using 6.0)

Are there any other solutions that would accomplish my objectives, that would be better suited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the back end side, the first step would be to create Read-only views. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805783/2993606