# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'read'

Tags: sql-server

Why do I get an incorrect syntax error near the keyword 'read'?

```
create view viewJab
as 
    select kojab,nmjabatan
    from jabatan
    with read only;
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure viewJab, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'read'.

Comment: Because that's not allowed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx If you want to create a read only view, there are multiple ways of doing that. Google is your friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805760/creating-readonly-views-in-sql-server

Comment: This post might also be of interest to you: [Creating read only views in SQL-Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805760/creating-readonly-views-in-sql-server) - sorry, only just noticed that David Brabant already mentioned this post. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
create view viewJab
with SCHEMABINDING
as select kojab,nmjabatan
from dbo.jabatan

DENY UPDATE ON dbo.viewjab TO username
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more info around why this would solve the problem please?

Comment: Good question! In fact, the 'With schemabinding' clause prevents the underlying tables (in this case jabatan) from being altered in such a way as this would affect the view! This is kind of the other way round and doesn't really answer the question at all. Also in the e.g. I gave above, the table that the view selects from needs to incorporate it's schema (i.e. dbo) which would be input as dbo.jabatan. I've edit the example to show this and added a 'permissions way' of achieving read only so long as you know the username of everyone you want to deny update capability to.

Comment: @russ You should edit your answer instead of posting essential parts as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

**CREATE VIEW:**

```
create view viewJab as 
select kojab,nmjabatan
from jabatan;
```

**TRIGGER:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ViewJab_Trigger_OnInsertOrUpdateOrDelete]
ON dbo.viewJab
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You are not allow to update this view!', 16, 1)     
END
```