# Which is faster? Query to a local table, or a programmed value list in a combobox control

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, vpn

I have a series of combo boxes on a form - and I have connected them to lists of data in the past by using a pass-through query to a sql server, and while this performs well in most cases, many of my users have been accessing the database using a VPN, and the response to populate them seems slow.

I started programming the system to populate a local table from the pass through query on form load - then, used a local query to show results in the proper order.  Once they select the first combo box the second combobox filters from there, to the third, and the fourth (in some cases I have more than 4 too),

All of this is intended so I don't have to connect to the server each time they change selections.  However, I am thinking that having a value list that is hard coded might be faster in performance for the lists that don't change - such as the highest level in the selection hiearchy (think of 3 or 4 comboboxes that effect each other and filter the next ones results).

Does anyone know if using a hardcoded value list in a combobox has a performance gain over a local query to a local table in MS Access?  I am using MS Access 2016 if it helps.

Comment: In general, any time you have to query the database, it's going to be slower...

Comment: _"for lists that don't change"_ You better be absolutely positive about this before you decide. Some lists change rarely - but that is not **never**. If these "lists" involve foreign key values in your database, then you should not hardcode.

Comment: Looks like you have two horses... race them?

Comment: You won't find a difference that any user would ever notice. Both methods will be magnitudes faster than the server access over VPN. So use what is better maintainable in your situation, or easier to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few things: you do NOT want to use a pass-through query for a listbox/combo box. NEVER!!!!

Why? The Access client cannot filter a PT query. This seems contradictory here.

First, lets be clear: the fastest way to pull data is a PT query - hands down.

However lets assume the combo box is large - say 3000 rows.

AND ALSO assume the combo box is bound (that means it saves a value to the form's bound recordset.

Well, remember the above rule!!! - Access client NEVER is able to filter the PT query.

So, if you have a report that you run? If your PT query is not PRE-FILTERED (the criteria exists in the PT query - even a stored procedure), then adding a where clause to the form (or report), or in this case a combo box WILL NOT WORK - the FULL data set is returned and can not be filtered.

So, if you have a PT query with 500,000 rows, and you do this:

```
docmd.OpenReport "rtpInvoice", acViewPreview,,"InvoiceNumber = 1234"
```

The above will pull 500,000 rows.

However, if you used a plane jane linked table, or best link to a view, and it ALSO has 500,000 rows? Well only 1 record comes down the network pipe!

So, if that combo box is bound to 5000 rows, and a simple navigation to the NEXT record occurs? Well, the combo box will of course have a single value - the underlying recordset of the bound form. But, it cannot filter + display the ONE value for the combo box (most combo boxes are multi-column - 1st column = PK, and 2nd column = some kind of description.

So, access is actually quite smart, and it will attempt to ONLY pulls the ONE value from the 5000 rows driving the combo box. But the exception to the rule is of course a PT query!

Again: Access client cannot filter a PT query.

So, if the combo box has a large data set AND ALSO is feed by a PT query, then things run slow as a dog. I had one system in which the PT query was returning about 100,000 rows. Just a simple navigation to the next record was slow as a dog.

Replacing the PT query with a linked view made the form work near instant. This is because out of the 100,000 rows, Access is able to ONLY pull the ONE row for display of the combo box and that 2nd column.

So, while a PT query is the fastest way to pull data? Yes, 100% true, but you ONLY want to use that speed advantage WHEN you need ALL OF the records of that PT query. If you going to filter AFTER or AGAINST the PT query (such as is done for a bound combo box), then a full scan of all records driving that combo box will occur.

The best approach? Dump the  PT queries for a combo box, and replace them with linked views. You can even specify a sort in the view (yes, it does shove in the top 100%). So ONLY place the view name in the combo box - don't fire up the query builder.

And, you can even get away using a direct link to a linked table. Again, Access client can filter that data set for the combo box.

So, there is no need to waste all that developer time building a PT query for a combo box and there is no need (nor advantage in speed) attempting to use code to load up and fill a combo box. But, if the PT query is going to return more than about 30 rows, then you  want to dump the PT query and use a linked table, or even better is a linked view.

I would not mess around with pulling a table from server to local - you could do that, but that's just extra code, extra pain, and it really gains you very little. And often it can make things worse. Why pull a whole table of lots of rows for a combo box, when just launching the form, access is smart enough to ONLY pull the one row required for display of the combo box. It will not pull the data until you click on the combo to make a choice.

If your PT queries are say over 50 or 100 rows to fill the combo box, and that combo box i a bound combo box? Then you have to dump the PT query, and use a linked table/view - and you get much better performance.

Comment: Well,  I appreciate all the detail.  I have a concern about linked tables - I have some users that have been creative enough to open it and get passed even me locking out the bypass key. If there is a linked table, then they have access to the actual data in full - and many times those tables allow them edit the data.  Is there any way of blocking that but keeping faster response time?

Comment: Well, they must be editing data in forms at some point? If you want to make the table (or view) read only, then you are free to do so with permissions. So, you could certainly use a view with read only permissions (select only permissions). Or you can "mess" with the view as this question shows:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805760/creating-readonly-views-in-sql-server      - - - -  So that view can be set as read only. But as noted, the PT query is ok, but NOT if Access client needs to try and filter the result - then a view or linked table is far better. So a view can be "select only".

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using tables linked from SQL server, consider using local tables for any values that rarely change, such as countries.

Have the master tables held within SQL server. When changes are needed, update the master table, and then import to your front end before deploying.

This way you will get better speed than from non-local tables, and are able to use these tables within queries and the like. And as the same data is held both within the Access front end and SQL Server back end, you can still create views within SQL server using the same data.

Regards,

Comment: I am already using a local table... and I am already importing it from the SQL server when the database loads. But, trying to determine if loading the values into the combobox and making it a value list is faster than displaying it as a query of that local table.